# Angular Simple Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

EDIT:  Realized I can't use the filter in the ng-repeat.

This then is my question rather;

If I have

```
<a ui-sref='itemPost({itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title.replace(regex2, " ").replace(regex1, "-").toLowerCase() })
```

How can I pass in the filter without writing it in the HTML?

Comment: maybe title is undefined at first call?

Comment: If you use `title.toLowerCase()` do you get an error as well?

Comment: Sorry had to re-ask the question as i'm not feeling too bright today!